# How to copy Gulden blockchain data from one wallet to another

Tags: blockchain

Which files should I copy from the blocks directory to copy all available blockchain data to another wallet.

Should I include:

- The blk*.dat files?
- The rev*.dat files?
- The index directory and its contents?

Furthermore would it be safe to symlink all but the latest .dat files instead of copying to save storage (assuming that the earlier .dat files never change).

After copying/linking, should I run the GuldenD with additional command line arguments like -rescan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm working off https://github.com/Gulden/gulden-official/blob/master/doc/files.md as a reference of the data directory structure for Gulden.
Relevant parts below:

> blocks/blk000??.dat: block data (custom, 128 MiB per file);
>
> blocks/rev000??.dat; block undo data (custom);
>
> blocks/index/*; block index (LevelDB);
>
> chainstate/*; block chain state database (LevelDB);

The above four essentially contain the blockchain, so would be required:

- blocks/blk*.dat - The actual blocks are written here
- blocks/index/* - A fast index into the above files is stored here, technically it is possible to find the blocks without this but it becomes a slow process
- chainstate/* - The UTXO (list of all unspent transactions) is stored here this is needed for verifying blocks - this can be regenerated if lost but is an expensive process.
- blocks/rev*.dat - This contains chainstate 'undo' information for the most recent blocks so that if the chain is reorganised the changes to the chainstate can be rolled back easily.

Under usual circumstances the older blocks/*.dat files would not be touched but there are possibly edge cases (pruning) where they might be, and future developments may want to touch them in order to free up space etc. - so I don't know if this is a safe assumption to rely on.

If the aim is to save space while hosting multiple wallets on one server a dedup filesystem is perhaps a safer way to do this without relying on a symlink.

If you are setting up a new GuldenD then no rescan or additional options are necessary after copying into place, if it is a GuldenD with existing addresses which may have received funds in the past then you would want to run a rescan.

Comment: Trying it the other way around now: just copying the wallet.dat file to a fully synched datadir. However I'm getting the following error: Error: wallet.dat corrupt, salvage failed
Should I copy/delete other files as well?

Comment: Just the wallet.dat should work. Make sure that the app is closed when you copy it and that permissions are right (e.g. are you maybe copying it as root? This can leave the file with permissions that the user running the program can't access)

Comment: Finaly solved. Turned out to be an hardly visible bug in a path.